# RxJS combine different sources into single stream of data

Tags: rxjs

I've to fetch data from an API which provides paged list of products. I want to fetch recursivly each page and then map each entry from response into another API call for getting each product details, yet getting the all products as a single stream of products. I've following -example- snippet.

```
import { flatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { concat, forkJoin, from, of } from 'rxjs';

const productListPage1 = [1, 2, 3];
const productListPage2 = [5, 6, 7];

function products() {
  return of({ data: productListPage1 }).pipe(
    flatMap((res) => {
      return concat(
        // fetch details of each product
        forkJoin(res.data.map((i) => of(i + 1))),
        from(productListPage2)
      );
    })
  );
}

products().subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
```

In this snippet productListPage1 is the first page, productListPage2 is next page. The result is following

```
[2, 3, 4]
5
6
7
```

while I need to achieve following results:

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

How could I modify above snippet to flatten the array [2, 3, 4] like rest of results?

Comment: Either your example is not accurate or your text description is not accurate, because you are making observables from variables in your example and you only have two pages, but in description you say you want to call multiple pages from API. Please improve your question. Your current example assumes that there are only two pages in the API.

Comment: Two pages are just example, rather I would call same function recursively to fetch next page, if exists.